# I get Errno 1 Operation not permitted when changing xattr

Tags: macos, macos-highsierra

I tried to remove two files from the system and then put them back. However since I put them back my Superdrive is not working. Files are

`IOCDStorageFamily.kext` and `IODVDStorageFamily.kext`

My assumption is that the problem is the xattr.

When I try to run the following command and add an xattr like the other files around:

```
sudo xattr -wx com.apple.rootless "`cat ~/Desktop/attribute`" IOCDStorageFamily.kext
```

I am getting:

```
xattr: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: 'IOCDStorageFamily.kext'
```

Everybody says it is the SIP, but I have disabled SIP `csrutil status`:

```
System Integrity Protection status: disabled.
```

When I run `ls -lO` we see two files that I care about

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 mh    wheel  -          102 Dec 19 21:07 IOCDStorageFamily.kext
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  restricted 102 Dec 19 21:11 IODVDStorageFamily.kext
drwxr-xr-x@ 3 root  wheel  restricted 102 Jul 16  2017 IOFireWireAVC.kext
```

File 1: I tried to make it with my user. no help. also I tried to remove "restricted" but that also didn't work.

File 2: Remained intact. Still can't edit xattr

File 3: Another file that is okay in its original form.

Help would be appreciated

(iMac 20" Early 2008, High Sierra)

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem on MacOS 13.5.2 Ventura. The problem was that my terminal app (iTerm2) didn't have full disk access.

To fix it, go to System Settings → Privacy & Security → Full Disk Access. Enable the checkbox for your terminal app. It will restart the terminal, after which you will be able to successfully run `xattr` on the files you want.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar xattr problem. It turned out that the file was locked. Even though I was owner and had read/write privileges, while the file was locked I only had read privileges. I right clicked the file (in finder)>clicked the lock icon at the bottom so I could make changes>opened the "general" section>and clicked the "Locked" button to unlock it. Or if you prefer terminal you can try this: SetFile -a l file.ext.
ref: [Command to unlock "Locked" files on OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/40749/command-to-unlock-locked-files-on-os-x)
and if that doesn't work for you then ref: [Mac OS X locked files on Sierra cannot be unlocked by clearing immutable bit on command line](https://superuser.com/questions/1246801/mac-os-x-locked-files-on-sierra-cannot-be-unlocked-by-clearing-immutable-bit-on)